# Router needs frequent reboot

Tags: networking, router

I'm sorry if I'm sparse on details, but I'm not sure what details I would need to provide.  I have a Linksys E1200 Router with a lot of computers on it (at least 10) plus wireless devices.  All the computers are connected via Ethernet and a port switch.  At least once a day, some computers will lose connection to the network altogether, and others will only lose internet access.  The problem is resolved by restarting the router, but this is a small business setting and it really interrupts things.

My question is this:  Will a different router resolve this problem?  I know they can get up to $300 or so, but I really don't know the difference between the cheaper one and more expensive ones (apart from dual frequencies and more ports).

Comment: Consumer grade routers often don't live very long, and when they start to die, the first signs are increasing slowness until the system will slow to a crawl, and stop passing more and more traffic until its offline entirely. Usually replacing it is the best bet, but I recommend stepping up to enterprise grade hardware, as it will last a good bit longer (but usually requires more technical knowhow to run successfully. ). I would also recommend you seperate your WiFi from your Router, so you would buy a wired router, and a wireless Access Point, instead of one device to do both.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you haven't done it recently, look for a firmware update for the router.

http://www.linksys.com/us/support-article?articleNum=148523

You could also try ensuring any air vents are clean and clear (in case it happens to be in a dusty environment, etc.) - to ensure you aren't having issues with overheating (probably not the case, but, to try to get as much life as possible out of your current router...)

Answer (score 0):

It is *possible* that a more expensive router could solve your problem. Without actively testing for specific problems it's hard to know. This depends on usage, primarily. It is best to try a firmware update first, however, as that's a much more likely culprit.

Incoming infodump:

One of the most common causes of router lockups (when not caused by bugs in firmware) is if the router is being overworked. I've had this problem a lot with Linksys routers in the past, actually, (about a decade ago) and it is one reason I don't use them much anymore. How much they have changed since I do not know.

This could be the case if you do a lot of torrenting, for example. Torrenting and other forms of peer-sharing use a lot of connections at once and open and close them often. If you *do* do a lot of torrenting you can try limiting the number of connections allowed in your torrenting software. Torrenting isn't the only thing that can cause this issue. Just an easy example. Anything that creates and destroys lots of connections often could cause this. Having so many computers on a single consumer-grade router could cause the same effect if they are all separately accessing the internet at the same time.

Another possibility is resolving and connecting wireless devices. If those 10+ devices are constantly dropping their wifi connections and reconnecting it could certainly put a strain on the router's CPU. Just maintaining so many wifi connections could be beyond the lowest-end routers' capability. Being in a noisy RF environment or being too far from the router for the router or device to reach each other well can contribute to this as more communication failures will happen and the router must put additional effort into correcting them. If you have a smartphone you should pick up a simple wifi-analysis app for your phone and use it to perform a basic site survey (I use Wifi Analyzer on Android). You can use it to perform a simple site survey of your location and see if you have a strong enough signal where your devices are used... generally -70dBm minimum with -60dBm or higher preferred. However, this will only check the router's integrated AP's ability to reach over distance and through impairments, remember that each device must also be able to transmit a signal back... and the strength of the signal produced by different devices can vary widely same as routers. Your router may have an integrated site survey feature in its administration page that would indicate the signal strength of connected devices (but not the router's strength at the device).

NOTE: 2 bars, 3 bars, 50 bars... none of that matters (for cell phones either actually). There is no standard for how many bars translates to what signal strength and different devices display the information differently. 5 of 5 bars could easily be -60dBm if that's what the manufacturer thought made sense (it doesn't). You need to use tools that give you the actual dBm measurement.

Generally, high-throughput tasks (such as watching movies online or gaming) does not, by itself, cause routers to lockup.

Both problems above are often resolved by using a higher end router. The wireless issues, in particular, can be improved by using 802.11ac for both the router and devices (each device must support it to benefit). Having more antennas on the router often translates into more transmit and receive lanes, allowing more devices to communicate simultaneously (instead of taking turns). It also enables some advanced capabilities that can help adjust for RF congestion or RF acoustics. Another thing to consider is dual-band which gives access to both 2.4ghz frequencies and the 5ghz frequencies. 2.4ghz frequencies typically do a better job of overcoming physical obstacles like walls and plumbing, however, the 2.4ghz band tends to be congested with other wireless devices (cordless phones, security systems, etc). the 5ghz band is much larger and not as many devices are using it but it has more difficulty punching through physical barriers. So it depends on what is causing your weakened signals as to which is better... but having access to both can help deal with both on a case by case basis. Last, but not least, you could consider getting a dedicated wifi access point and disable the router's integrated AP so it just handles routing... eliminating the need for your router to use any CPU for managing wifi connections.

You can also purchase a router with a more powerful processor/more memory but there's no way to really determine how much processing power or memory a consumer-grade router has besides doing your homework on each one. Even then it's not always a one-to-one comparison, depending on how efficient the router's firmware is and/or how many/what features are offered/in use. However, it is one of the things that make the $150+ routers as expensive as they are. Doing so would likely help if the router is being overwhelmed by the number of connections it is routing.

Again, all of this is supposition and guesswork. Actual testing is required to determine how much of what I've said applies to your case. This can either be done by your friendly neighborhood computer tech or you can do much of it yourself with various tools available cheap/free online.

If all else fails, make sure the router is connected to a good surge protector (not a power strip, a surge protector... surge protectors typically have power strips integrated... but not the other way around). Belkin and APC both make pretty good units. The reason for this is power spikes and drop-offs in your house voltage could cause the router to malfunction without actually damaging it. The power adapter that comes with your router is supposed to provide power conditioning adequate for the device but environments with extraordinarily unstable voltage could exceed the router's power adapter's ability to cope. This is quite rare but I've seen it a few times now. Most surge protectors, simply by the nature of how they work, provide additional power conditioning.

Comment: Thanks for all that information.  There is not torrenting happening, but lots of database usage and file transfering.  I'll try a firmware update and keeping it free of dust and see what it gets me.

Comment: Database usage could potentially cause it as well (lots of small, short connections to retrieve bits of data). But, yes, I would definitely try a firmware update and anti-overheat measures first.